# Unable to move this text up in a specific div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move this paragraph of text upwards in a div, so that it looks uniform, but I am unable to. In the particles class I changed the position to absolute but that causes the text on other divs to overlap onto this one. I tried adding `padding-bottom: 30px;` in the section about p class but that just increases the size of the div from the top.

```css
#particles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #00a1de;
}
section.about {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
section.about p {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles">
  <section class="container-fluid about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin congue vel erat sed efficitur. Nullam vitae sagittis nisi. In vulputate sit amet lorem at pharetra. Nam a imperdiet augue. Vivamus hendrerit ex id congue bibendum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to JavaScript, so I removed the tag.

Comment: @Shashank have you checked my answer? click run code snippet and then full page, then check whether you want it like that or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you correctly, then you need this -

```css
#particles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #00a1de;
}
section.about {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* This line */
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
section.about p {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles">
  <section class="container-fluid about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin congue vel erat sed efficitur. Nullam vitae sagittis nisi. In vulputate sit amet lorem at pharetra. Nam a imperdiet augue. Vivamus hendrerit ex id congue bibendum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I added the `transform: translate(-50%)` to shift the `section.about` up.

Is that you wanted?

Answer (score 5):

Remove position absolute.

```
section.about {
/*position: absolute;*/
left: 0;
/*top: 50%;*/
padding: 0 10px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The line of text disappeared when I did that.